# How do i stop Quicktime from opening previous videos?

Tags: macos, quicktime

I'm on OSX Lion and this is driving me crazy. Whenever i watch a video in quicktime and close it, then open another video, the previous video that i played also comes up.

Is there a way to not have the previous video(s) come up when opening quicktime besides closing out the windows, then quitting, everytime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That feature is part of Lion and QuickTimeX, but you can disable it.

Open your terminal (/Application/Utilities/Terminal.app) or use Spotlight to find the Terminal and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

That should stop QuickTime from saving the opened windows when you quit it.

If you want to revert the behavior, change the "false" to "true".

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not work for me. But the commands below worked:

```
defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX NSRecentDocumentsLimit 0
defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.LSSharedFileList RecentDocuments -dict-add MaxAmount 0
```

You can run these commands in the Terminal(`/Application/Utilities/Terminal.app` or using the Spotlight).